# The C Programming Language, confusion when comparing solution of Exercise 1-9 to 1-12

Tags: c

As a programming novice I have been trying to teach myself C to better understand computers using The C Programming Language (2nd Edition).

This site has been very helpful so far in troubleshooting problems but there is one problem I can't get my head around. It is my proposed solution to exercise 1-12 using my solution to 1-9 as a backdrop. I was wondering if anyone in this online community would kindly point out where I'm going wrong.

Exercise 1-9 asks you to "*Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one of more blanks by a single blank*"

There are many ways to skin the proverbial cat here but the solution that reads most simply to me is this:

```
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
   if(c == ' ')
     {
        putchar(' ');
        while((c = getchar()) == ' ') // if there are subsequent blanks
        ; // do nothing
     }

   if(c != EOF)
    putchar(c);
  }
```

Now Exercise 1-12 is asking you to "*Write a program that prints its input one word per line.*"

My first attempt was successful but an oversimplification of the problem.

```
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{  if(c == ' ')
     putchar('\n');

else
  putchar(c);
}
```

So I've tried to rectify this to accept a much wider range of inputs and here is the result

```
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
 {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
     {
      putchar('\n');
      while((c = getchar()) == ' ' || (c = getchar()) == '\t' || (c = getchar()) == '\n')
      ;
     }

    if(c != EOF)
     putchar(c);
 }
```

Now I know this is wrong when I run it and I have looked up online other very simple ways to solve the problem.

My issue here is that I don't understand why it doesn't work. To me if the solution to 1-9 works I don't understand why it fails when I take the same principle to 1-12. Anyone who could point this out would be appreciated!

Comment: The function [`isspace`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) in `#include <ctype.h>` may be of interest to you.

Comment: You should not call getchar() for each comparison in the second while statement.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was almost correct, but `getchar()` *consumes* one character of input on every invocation.

You could have written

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
```

because the `||` operator is processed left-to-right with so called sequence point in between;

though clearer is to move the initialization of `c` out of the loop  condition.

Finally, using `isspace` this would consume *any* whitespace characters, with much less typing:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int c;
do {
   c = getchar();
} while (isspace(c));
```

Comment: I appreciate the very clear answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
while((c = getchar()) == ' ' || (c = getchar()) == '\t' || (c = getchar()) == '\n')
           ^                         ^                          ^
```

You're calling `getchar()` three times. Those calls read three characters, and you compare the first against space, second against `\t` and third against `\n`. (The calls are separated by `||`, so there should be no issues with undefined sequencing.)

Instead, use temp variable:

```
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
} while (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n');
```

Using `isspace()` from `ctype.h` would probably be better too.

Comment: I see where I went wrong, using a temp variable makes sense. My only issue is that functions haven't been covered yet in the book but maybe I should be prepared to not follow it too strictly/chronologically..

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth mentioning a sane and readable way to write this code without "assignment inside conditions", "most operators on a single line wins a price" or other such bad and dangerous habits picked up from that old book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    int c = getchar();
    if (isspace(c))
    {
      putchar('\n');       // at first space found, print line feed
      do
        c = getchar();
      while(isspace(c));   // discard any additional spaces
    }

    if(c == EOF)           // here c will not be a space, but possibly EOF
    {
      break;
    }

    putchar(c);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting comments on the book. I would often read how it was the C "bible" but I guess nothing is perfect. I'll keep in mind potential bad habits. Thank you for the answer as well! I have to say this website is wonderful and it's users  are very generous :)

Comment: Argument of `isspace` should be cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @tommie997 Keep in mind that cramming as much code into as few lines as possible can reduce the page count of a textbook by quite a few pages.  At just a few pennies per textbook, over thousands of textbooks over multiple years that adds up to a really nice swimming pool for the publisher...

Comment: @tommie997, I would not, myself, characterize the second edition of K&R as the C Bible, or anything like it.  The *first* edition had a status more like that for a while after its publication, but the second edition is just another C textbook, albeit by authors deserving of considerable respect in the area.  And at this point, however, even the second edition is seriously out of date.  You can certainly learn C from it, but I would not automatically defer to it above other sources.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili *Argument of `isspace` should be cast to `unsigned char`*  That's not necessary here. That's only necessary when passing a `char` value to `isspace()` because it might ge sign-extended.  The value here is already an `int` containing the proper representation of the input data.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what if `int` is negative? Is it OK because `getchar` has some kind of guarantee about that? The value of the argument should be representable with an `unsigned char`, or it causes undefined behavior. Especially considering the code does not check for `EOF` before `isspace` so it definitely causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @tommie997 It _was_ the C bible up to year 1989. Then it turned mostly obsolete. But it never had good coding practice because it was written before good coding practice was invented.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili All real-world systems have `getchar` return either a positive number or `EOF`. Even EBCDIC ones and the various "extended ASCII" non-standards. Had I stored the result in a `char` it would have been another story though.

Comment: @Lundin is it OK to pass `EOF` to `isspace`? The argument should be representable as an `unsigned char` and it maybe using a lookup table, so I'd say not checking for `EOF` before `isspace` is UB.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Instead of guessing how the function works, check the documentation. C17 7.4 ctype.h chapter: "In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the
argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

If your char is not a space then you will try to get another char from the user instead of analyzing the one that was entered.

correct your while to call it only once:

```c
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
```